# Enhancing Generalization in DRL Agents in Static Data Environments

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-learning, deep-rl, proximal-policy-optimization, generalization

**Context:** I'm working with a deep reinforcement learning (DRL) agent in a market-like environment where its actions do not affect the environment. The environment uses historical data up to a certain date for training, and data following this date is reserved for evaluation. Each timestep 't' in the training phase provides the agent with the corresponding row from the dataset.

**Problem:** When training extends beyond 'T' timesteps, the agent starts seeing the same observations repeatedly, which raises concerns about overfitting and its ability to generalize. Although the replay buffer helps by randomly sampling observations for updating model weights, I'm worried that in long-term training, the agent might learn the specific transitions in the training dataset rather than developing a generalizable solution.

**Question:** How can I enhance the DRL agent's ability to generalize in this static, data-driven training environment? Are there specific training strategies or adjustments that can encourage the agent to develop strategies that are generalizable and effective, rather than just memorizing the training dataset?

Comment: welcome to AI Stack Exchange! If possible, it might help to explain a little more about the environment if you are able to provide details. If the actions of the agent do not affect the environment, this problem might be better solved with other methods. Thank you for this high-quality question, and we hope to see more of your questions here soon!